# Mouse pointer locked around a point

Tags: math, rotation, equation

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but if so I could not find it before posting this.

In a nutshell, I want to do this:
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyY92.png)

I want a pointer (red) to rotate about the circle (blue) according to where the mouse is located. (If picture is not visible, it depicts a blue circle with a red triangle pointing away from it, towards the mouse).

If possible, please answer with a general mathematical equation rather than specific code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a *normal cartesian coordinate space*, with the X axis going to the right and the Y axis going up, you first need to calculate the angle to the mouse coordinate (M) to the circle origin (O):

```
theta = atan2(M.y - O.y, M.x - O.x)
```

you can then calculate the position of a point (P) orbiting the circle at radius (r) with:

```
P.x = r * cos(theta)
P.y = r * sin(theta)
```

The atan2(y, x) function is a common math library function that just computes atan(y / x) but takes the relative signs of x and y into account to determine the correct quadrant.

Comment: Might be going beyond the call of duty a bit, but could you try and explain the process behind this how a 15 year old may understand it? Thanks :)